# Python add text to matplotlib.image.AxesImage instance

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

i have this code for creating a series of image from a series of matrixes, and in each image i want to add a specific text. this is my typical code :

```
ax = axes([0,0,1,1])

for i in range(0,5):
    text(1,1,str(i))
    ax.imshow(a[:,:,i],origin='lower')
    savefig(str("%04d" % int(i))+'.png',format="png")
    del ax.texts[-1]
```

but the problem is that as the number of iteration increases, the speed decease and it becomes so so slow. It seems that there is something wrong with opening a lot of windows in background.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added this single line at the end of the loop and it works fine now. It was simply the problem of accumulating previuosly opened figures in the memory.

```
ax = axes([0,0,1,1])

for i in range(0,5):
    text(1,1,str(i))
    ax.imshow(a[:,:,i],origin='lower')
    savefig(str("%04d" % int(i))+'.png',format="png")
    del ax.texts[-1] 
    close(gcf())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new image and text objects every loop reuse the objects.

```
ax = axes([0,0,1,1])
t = text(1,1,str(0))
img = ax.imshow(a[:,:,0],origin='lower')

for i in range(0,5):
    t.set_text(str(i)
    img.set_data(a[:,:,i])
    savefig(str("%04d" % int(i))+'.png',format="png")
```

also see

[Visualization of 3D-numpy-array frame by frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563295/visualization-of-3d-numpy-array-frame-by-frame/11563414#11563414)

Comment: Thanx for the answer! i simply add close(gcf()) and it works. i also tried yours, the speed is the same. but for your case, we have to define a new figure object to works.

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept it, if you used a different solution, please post what you used and accept your own answer.