# Show several plots in a scrollable widget with PyQt and matplotlib

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, qscrollarea

Since I didn't get an answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179893/creating-a-scrollable-multiplot-with-pythons-pylab) question I tried solving it with PyQt.
Apparently, it's not that easy, when QScrollArea is involved...

I wrote a small test that basically does what I'm looking for, but it's not showing the scroll area and the plots inside it as I expected:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os,sys

#import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
qwidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
qlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(qwidget)
qwidget.setLayout(qlayout)

qscroll = QtGui.QScrollArea(qwidget)
qscroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
qscroll.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
qlayout.addWidget(qscroll)

qscrollContents = QtGui.QWidget()
qscrollLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(qscrollContents)
qscrollLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000))

qscroll.setWidget(qscrollContents)
qscroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

for i in xrange(5):
  qfigWidget = QtGui.QWidget(qscrollContents)
  fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
  canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
  canvas.setParent(qfigWidget)
  toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas, qfigWidget)
  axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
  axes.plot([1,2,3,4])
  qscrollLayout.addWidget(qfigWidget)

qscrollContents.setLayout(qscrollLayout)

qwidget.show()
exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Can anyone explain why it's not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `QWidget` for each plot. But you don't put your `canvas` or `toolbar` in it via a layout, so they can't communicate the size information with the `QWidget`. By default, a `QWidget` has no `minimumSize` and the widget/layout inside the `QScrollArea` can make them as small as it wants in order to fit the available space (which is the size of `QScrollArea`).

Adding plots via layout helps, but I find that the `FigureCanvas` widget also doesn't have any minimum size so it can shrink. For a quick fix, you can set a `minimumSize`. The loop part with these fixes should look like this:

```
for i in xrange(5):
  qfigWidget = QtGui.QWidget(qscrollContents)

  fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
  canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
  canvas.setParent(qfigWidget)
  toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas, qfigWidget)
  axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
  axes.plot([1,2,3,4])

  # place plot components in a layout
  plotLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
  plotLayout.addWidget(canvas)
  plotLayout.addWidget(toolbar)
  qfigWidget.setLayout(plotLayout)

  # prevent the canvas to shrink beyond a point
  # original size looks like a good minimum size
  canvas.setMinimumSize(canvas.size())

  qscrollLayout.addWidget(qfigWidget)
```

Comment: Awesome! It's much better than the fix that I came up with.