# (Matplotlib, python) long subplots, scrolling

Tags: python, matplotlib, scroll, visualization, subplot

I would like to create a pdf file [by using plt.savefig("~~~.pdf")] 
containing lots of (about 20) subplots 
each of which is drawing timeseries data.
I am using a matplotlib library with python language.

Each subplot may be long, and I want to put the subplots 
horizontally.
Therefore, the figure should be very long (horizontally), so the horizontal scroll bar should be needed!

Is there any way to do this?
some example code will be appreciated!

The following is my sample code.
I just wanted to draw 10 sine graphs arranged horizontally
and save it as pdf file. 
(but I'm not pretty good at this. so the code may looks to be weird to you.. :( )

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y=np.sin(x)

numplots=10
nr=1
nc=numplots
size_x=nc*50
size_y=size_x*3/4

fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(size_x,size_y))
for i in range(nc):
    ctr=i+1
    ax=fig.add_subplot(nr,nc,ctr)

    ax.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("longplot.pdf")
plt.clf()
```

Thank you!

Comment: you want the plots to be scrollable in a pdf? don't think that is possible

Comment: yeah, exactly.. Ah.. is it impossible? then may it be possible to draw a single very long figure (not subplots) with horizontal scroll in a pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You should do that using the backend "matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf". This enables you to save matplotlib graphs in pdf format.
I have simplified your code a bit, here is a working example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = np.sin(x)

nr = 10
nc = 1

for i in range(nr):    
    plt.subplot(nr, nc, i + 1)
    plt.plot(x, y)    

pdf = PdfPages('longplot.pdf')
pdf.savefig()

pdf.close()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. a pdf file created shows 10 subplots. But each one is a little small (is shrunk to be fitted in a one page.) Is it possible to make each subplot larger and make a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Try and check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179893/creating-a-scrollable-multiplot-with-pythons-pylab.

Answer (score 0):

In the link below there is a solution, which can help you, since it was helpful to me either.
[Scrollbar on Matplotlib showing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page)

But if you have many subplots, I am afraid your problem won't be solved. Since it will shrink each graph anyway. In that case it will be better to break your graphs into smaller and separate parts.