# Show image without scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given an image of 500x500 pixels I want to show that image 1:1 on my screen. Additionally I want to have an x and y axes.

- `plt.imshow()` automatically adds axes to my image and centers the image in the window, but the image is scaled and not shown as 500x500 pixels on my screen.
- `fig.figimage()` shows the image 1:1 on my screen but adds no axes and displays the image in the bottom left corner of the window. Especially maximizing the window / resizing the windows does not change the size of image.

Now what I need, is a combination of both – diplay the image 1:1 like `fig.figshow` does, add the axes that `plt.imshow()` adds and display the image centered like `plt.imshow()` does.

How can I do that? 
Or in other terms: How to tell `plt.imshow()` to display im image unscaled like `fig.figimage()` does?

Sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

width=500;
height=500;

# using plt.imshow()
dummyImage = np.zeros((width, height))
plt.imshow(dummyImage)
plt.show()

# using fig.figimage()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
fig.figimage(dummyImage)
plt.show()
```

Result:

using `plt.imshow()`: not exactly 500x500 pixels and actual size depends on size of the window.
[image]

using `fig.figimage()`: exactly 500x500 pixels, independent of window size

[image]

Comment: Try and convert it to a PNG, then use `IPython.display.Image` to display it. Other than that, I don't know a way to make it not scale.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to display it directly and using matplotlib if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to do a little bit of calculation yourself. 
Say, you want 50 pixel margin on all sides, and you have a dpi of 100, you can then calculate the figure size to be `figsize=((width+2*margin)/dpi, (height+2*margin)/dpi)` inches. You would then need to calculate the borders, e.g. the left border will be margin divided by dpi divided by figure width. You can set the calculated figure size (`figsize` argument of `plt.figure()`) and borders (using `subplots_adjust`) to your figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

width=500 # pixels
height=150
margin=50 # pixels
dpi=100. # dots per inch

figsize=((width+2*margin)/dpi, (height+2*margin)/dpi) # inches
left = margin/dpi/figsize[0] #axes ratio
bottom = margin/dpi/figsize[1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=bottom, right=1.-left, top=1.-bottom)

dummyImage = np.zeros((height, width))
plt.imshow(dummyImage)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that to have an image of dimensions width `width` and height `height`, you need an array `np.zeros((height, width))`, not the inverse.

In order to make sure the figure keeps its original size, one may add the following code, which resizes the figure back to its original size on every attempt to change the figure size:

```
def update(event=None):
    fig.set_size_inches(figsize)

update()
ci = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! That's already close, but the widht seems to be 500 including the tiks (the markings on the y axis). I would require 500 just for the image itself. Do you know a way to make sure the figure does not resize when maximizing the window?

Comment: The width should be the width without the ticks. One can see that this is correct when exporting the figure using `savefig`. Now there seems indeed to be a problem, which is that the Window might resize the figure upon creation. This seems to be the case here, using QtAgg backend. It does not occur using TkAgg backend. Would you be happy to use Tk?

Comment: I added `import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` but then the image is far away from 500 px. Any idea what could cause this? I tried your code addition to keep the figure to it's original size. This works when using TkAgg in terms of same size as when opening the window, but the image size is still larger than 500 px.

Comment: Tried changing the dpi variable, but even setting it to 200 changes nothing - my image is about 750 px wide instead of 500 px. I am on a 4k display and the axes are large and a little bit washed out. Seems like TkAgg has problems with high DPI. I just have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Update: Changing DPI affects only the axes, not the image size itself which stays at roughly 750 px instead of 500 px ): And I figured out why: Windows DPI scaling is set to 150%. Changing the figsize line to `figsize=((width/1.5+2*margin)/dpi, (height/1.5+2*margin)/dpi)`helps :-) Thank you!

Comment: The code above makes sure the figure is always the same size, independent on the dpi; thus far it's expected that changing dpi only scales the axis spines and labels. Concerning the figure size of 750px, I cannot reproduce this issue. Could it be a systems setting (I know that sometimes Windows10 likes to ship with 125% dpi scaling).

Comment: As the QtAgg has less problems with high DPI: Do you have any idea how one could prevent resizing here? Our latest comments were overlapping - yes, windows DPI scaling is the problems on TkAgg.

Comment: Right click on python.exe - compatability - behaviour by dpi scaling set to application keeps windows frm scaling at TkAgg :-) I noted one more thing: When maximizing the window, the background next to the figure is grey instead of white. Any idea how to fix that? Any any idea how to center the figure in the window? Anyway, you already helped me a lot and with great effort, so I already not select your reply as answer :-)

Comment: The gray background comes from the Tk application, you cannot easily change that. One option, which would give you anyways much more control would of course be to embed the figure into a custom Tk or PyQt GUI (This would also allow you to use PyQt and prevent the small resize in PyQt itself.) Then changing the background would be easily possible. As an example for PyQt, you may look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page)'s answer.