# Python: Showing multiple images in one figure WITHOUT scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing some image processing in Python and I would like to plot 4 images (they are all 224x224x3 np arrays) in one figure, add some titles and save the whole figure as png.

Obviously, I can do this using plt and subplot:

```
        f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
        ax = axs[0, 0]
        ax.imshow(img1)
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_title('original')

        ax = axs[1, 0]
        ax.imshow(img2)
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_title('blur + noise')

        ax = axs[0, 1]
        ax.imshow(img3)
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_title('restored a')

        ax = axs[1, 1]
        ax.imshow(img4)
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_title('restored b')
```

However this will apply scaling to the different images and I would like to display the images in their original resolution without any interpolation being applied. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour in plt? I found some other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346033/show-image-without-scaling/) that asked a similar question, however it only answers how to display one single image without scaling.

Thanks for your help,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure is essentially the same as in the linked question,
[Show image without scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346033/show-image-without-scaling/).

In addition to the margin and the image size(s) you need to take into account the spacing between the subplots.

The size of the figure in pixels is then

```
size_image_A + size_image_B + 2* margin + spacing
```

This needs to be converted to the size in inched by dividing by the figure `dpi`.
The subplots_adjust parameters need to be extended by the spacing in relative axes units.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

images = [np.random.rayleigh((i+1)/8., size=(180, 200, 3)) for i in range(4)]


margin=50 # pixels
spacing =35 # pixels
dpi=100. # dots per inch

width = (200+200+2*margin+spacing)/dpi # inches
height= (180+180+2*margin+spacing)/dpi

left = margin/dpi/width #axes ratio
bottom = margin/dpi/height
wspace = spacing/float(200)

fig, axes  = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(width,height), dpi=dpi)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=bottom, right=1.-left, top=1.-bottom, 
                    wspace=wspace, hspace=wspace)

for ax, im, name in zip(axes.flatten(),images, list("ABCD")):
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_title('restored {}'.format(name))
    ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]