# Plot multiple subplots python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple sublpots using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=3,squeeze= False, figsize = (40, 40))
i = 0
for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        img = image.imread("black.png")
        i = i+1
        col.axis("off")
        col.set_title("group_", fontsize = 20) 
        col.imshow(img) # consider I,m plottinf some image
```

When I'm plotting fewer subplots the subplots are very close together
[image]

However When I'm plotting more subplots there is a considerable gap between horizontal subplots.

[image]

Let me know how can I plot such that the plots are close to each other

Note: This may look like duplicate but I was not able to find a solution by browsing stackoverflow to fix this issue

Comment: have you tried  [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

Comment: Some questions: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376052/preventing-matplotlib-from-decrease-the-size-of-plotted-images-as-number-of-imag), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475508/how-to-combine-gridspec-with-plt-subplots-to-eliminate-space-between-rows-of-s), [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing is an unfortunate combination of `figsize` parameter of `plt.subplots()` and `imshow(aspect="")` in conjunction with your image size. In particular, all those are constraining the vertical/horizontal spaces.

In my case, going from `figsize=(40, 40)` to `figsize=(8, 24)` somewhat fixed the issue.

## `figsize=(40, 40)`

[image: so_figsize_error]

## `figsize=(8, 24)`

[image: so_figsize_fixed]

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the horizontal and vertical space between subplots with `hspace` and `wspace`.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(hspace = ..., wspace = ...)
```

Comment: I tried it but still it didn't solved my problem. hspace is changing and wspace is increasing but not decreasing then what I already have.

Comment: @MNA, did you also try negative values? it supports negative values and e.g. wspace=-0.6 would decrease space compared to default.