# How to display large Matplotlib window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, visualization

I tried to show a large Matplotlib Pyplot figure (`figsize=(9, 36)`) from a Python command line code in Windows 7.

It gave this warning and generated a figure with all subplots squeezed:

```
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1350x5466+8+30 on QWidgetWindow/
'MainWindowClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1350x882+8+30 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom 
margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 67x66, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
```

Is there any way to solve the issue and plot the intact figure?

Comment: The figure needs to fit in the screen, if you are using an interactive backend.

Comment: So I can only make an image PNG or other files (using hardcopy backends) if the plot is larger than the screen, without the capability to display it interactively?

Comment: Yes. If you want to display it interactively, it needs to fit in the screen.

Comment: One option you have is to create your custom plotting window inside of which you use scrollbars, such that the figure may be larger than the screen. This would be shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page).