# Add vertical scroll bar to embedded matplotlib canvas while keeping its horizontal size occupying the entire QScrollArea

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside2, qscrollarea

I've created a GUI in `pyside2` with an embedded `matplotlib` canvas. I'm planning to display a lot of information on this canvas, so I need more vertical space. I figured I could place the canvas inside a `QScrollArea` and create a "tall" figure with some subplots below each other.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page) comes close to what I want, but I don't want horizontal scrolling at all. Rather, **I'd like my canvas to expand/shrink according to the GUI, fully occupying the available horizontal space inside the `QScrollArea`**, while still only allowing for vertical scrolling of the figure.

The following code is a MRE without any scrollbars:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow, 
                               QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas,
                                                NavigationToolbar2QT as Navbar)
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Main Window setup
        self.showMaximized()
        self.frame = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Buttons (left column)
        buttons_row = QHBoxLayout()

        self.plot_above_button = QPushButton(self, text='Plot Data Above')
        self.plot_above_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_above)
        buttons_row.addWidget(self.plot_above_button)

        self.plot_below_button = QPushButton(self, text='Plot Data Below')
        self.plot_below_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_below)
        buttons_row.addWidget(self.plot_below_button)

        main_layout.addLayout(buttons_row)

        # Plot (right column)
        right_column = QVBoxLayout()

        self.fig = Figure(facecolor='white')
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7])
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1])

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self)

        right_column.addWidget(self.canvas)
        right_column.addWidget(Navbar(self.canvas, self.frame))
        main_layout.addLayout(right_column)

    def plot_above(self):
        self.ax1.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
        self.canvas.draw()

    def plot_below(self):
        self.ax2.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    gui = MyApp()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the GUI I see when I execute the code above:

[image]

As you can see, the canvas occupies the entire available space, vertically and horizontally. Except for the lacking vertical scrollbar, this is exactly what I want.

Now, if I try to place `self.canvas` inside a `QScrollArea`, by adding these lines to my code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QScrollArea  # additional import

        # ...
        self.canvas.setParent(self)  # this is old code 

        # new code starts here
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.canvas)

        right_column.addWidget(scroll_area)
        right_column.addWidget(Navbar(self.canvas, self.frame))  # this is old code
        # ...
```

I now end up with:

[image]

Instead of automatically adjusting its size, the figure just "sits" inside the `QScrollArea`, initialized with the default figsize value.

I also tried to manually resize the figure, by writing e.g.:

```
        self.fig = Figure(facecolor='white', figsize=(11, 12))
```

Which gives me:

[image]

This is very close to what I want, but also very hacky: I empirically chose the figsize `(11, 12)` based on how the canvas looks like on my screen, but these values could be different in another screen or if I add extra widgets to the left side. The canvas also doesn't resize along with the main window.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Try `scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)`

Comment: @alec thanks for your comment, I tried playing around with your suggestion but unfortunately the results were the same as my first image (i.e. no scrollbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to solve this for another day, I finally figured it out. I'm writing the answer here in case anyone stumbles into this issue in the future.

We can reimplement `resizeEvent` of the GUI to resize the canvas width to the `QScrollArea` current width:

```
    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        self.canvas.resize(self.scroll_area.width(), self.canvas.height())
        super().resizeEvent(e)
```

If I call `self.showMaximized()` at the end of the init method, the resize will trigger automatically. This means that the canvas is properly resized when the window is first shown, and it adapts when I change the window size.

This is the outcome:

[image]

And the full code used to generate the GUI:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow, 
                            QPushButton, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas,
                                                NavigationToolbar2QT as Navbar)
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Main Window setup
        self.frame = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Buttons (left column)
        buttons_row = QHBoxLayout()

        self.plot_above_button = QPushButton(self, text='Plot Data Above')
        self.plot_above_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_above)
        buttons_row.addWidget(self.plot_above_button)

        self.plot_below_button = QPushButton(self, text='Plot Data Below')
        self.plot_below_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_below)
        buttons_row.addWidget(self.plot_below_button)

        main_layout.addLayout(buttons_row)

        # Plot (right column)
        right_column = QVBoxLayout()

        self.fig = Figure(facecolor='white', figsize=(12, 12))
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7])
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1])
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.canvas)

        right_column.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        right_column.addWidget(Navbar(self.canvas, self.frame))
        main_layout.addLayout(right_column)

        self.showMaximized()

    def plot_above(self):
        self.ax1.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
        self.canvas.draw()

    def plot_below(self):
        self.ax2.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
        self.canvas.draw()

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        self.canvas.resize(self.scroll_area.width(), self.canvas.height())
        super().resizeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    gui = MyApp()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```