# Problem resizing plot on tkinter figure canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Python 3.9 on Mac running OS 11.6.1. My application involves placing a plot on a frame inside my root window, and I'm struggling to get the plot to take up a larger portion of the window. I thought `rcParams` in `matplotlib.pyplot` would take care of this, but I must be overlooking something.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,TOP,BOTH

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [18,10]

root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Root Window")
root.geometry('1500x1000')

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

canvas_frame=Frame(root) # also tried adjusting size of frame but that didn't help
canvas_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```

For my actual application, I need for `canvas` to have a frame as its parent and not simply `root`, which is why `canvas_frame` is introduced above.

Comment: _"I need for canvas to have a frame as its parent and not simply root"_ It's not clear what is stopping you from doing that. Is the problem as simple as adding `fill="both"` when calling `canvas_frame.pack`?

Comment: @BryanOakley: I made that comment just to emphasize that, for my application, I'd like to follow the two-step approach I've used here-namely putting the canvas on a frame first and not directly putting the canvas on the root. I hope that makes sense. 

I did try inserting ```fill="both" ``` as you suggested, but that merely moved the plot to the top left of my screen.

Comment: Instead of canvas.pack is there an .center or alternative?

Comment: This problem doesn't have to do with adding the canvas to the window in the correct way so much as removing the extra space from inside the canvas. If you add a line after creating the canvas that fills it with red, and then rapidly drag the window's sides around to resize it, the plot will flicker, and you can see the red behind. The red fills the whole window, so the canvas is filling as much of the window as it can. Changing the way you add the canvas to the window is not going to do much. Just eliminating the possibilities.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin--thanks for sharing this observation. This problem has me really stuck.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin   I'm curious how to fill the canvas with a color such as red. I've tried to track down the documentation for how this is done in a separate line as you suggest but haven't uncovered anything.

Comment: To fill the canvas with a certain color, you can use `bg="red"`. To test this yourself, just add `canvas.get_tk_widget().config(bg="red")` right before you call `root.mainloop()`. Then, unmaximize the window and drag one of the sides quickly back and forth. If your computer is slow enough (like mine), you should be able to see flickers of red filling the window.

Comment: Have you tried to add the option `fill=BOTH' when packing `canvas_frame``?

Comment: Yes, I have--see response above from 1/5 20:23. This merely moves the plot to the top left of my window.

Comment: This had not been an issue for me a few weeks ago, so I uninstalled the newest matplotlib and went back to 3.4.0 instead. That solved the problem.

Comment: Would you mind including a screenshot of how this looks for you, and what improvement you would like to see?

Comment: @mdurant -- I apologize for not getting back to you with a screenshot. However, I've posted a similar problem (with image) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598913/problem-resizing-plot-on-tkinter-figure-canvas 

The primary difference is that the plot is an animation, and it's being embedded on a Toplevel instead of a Frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.07, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

this is output, figure now takes more screen area %
[[image: figure now takes more screen realestate1]

Comment: --Thanks so much for your solution. You may be interested in a similar problem (with image) I posted at stackoverflow.com/questions/70598913/… The primary difference is that the plot is an animation, and it's being embedded on a Toplevel instead of a Frame.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to the suggestion of changing the margins, you could also add `fill=BOTH` to the canvas widget.

```
canvas_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
```

This makes the figure canvas take up more space, but the plot doesn't take the whole window. However, if I resize the window, then the plot takes the whole window.