# How to update artists in scrollable, matplotlib and multiplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I'm trying to create a scrollable multiplot based on the answer to this question:
[Creating a scrollable multiplot with python's pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179893/creating-a-scrollable-multiplot-with-pythons-pylab/12237591#comment55399508_12237591)

Lines created using `ax.plot()` are updating correctly, however I'm unable to figure out how to update artists created using `xvlines()` and `fill_between()`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

#create dataframes
dfs={}
for x in range(100):
    col1=np.random.normal(10,0.5,30)
    col2=(np.repeat([5,8,7],np.round(np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1)*31)[0].tolist()))[:30]
    col3=np.random.randint(4,size=30)
    dfs[x]=pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1,'col2':col2,'col3':col3})

#create figure,axis,subplot
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1,hspace=0,wspace=0,left=0.1,bottom=0.1)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax.set_ylim([0,12])

#slider
frame=0
axframe = plt.axes([0.13, 0.02, 0.75, 0.03])
sframe = Slider(axframe, 'frame', 0, 99, valinit=0,valfmt='%d')

#plots
ln1,=ax.plot(dfs[0].index,dfs[0]['col1'])
ln2,=ax.plot(dfs[0].index,dfs[0]['col2'],c='black')

#artists
ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==5,facecolor='r',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==8,facecolor='b',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==7,facecolor='g',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
ax.vlines(x=dfs[0]['col3'].index,ymin=0,ymax=dfs[0]['col3'],color='black')

#update plots
def update(val):
    frame = np.floor(sframe.val)
    ln1.set_ydata(dfs[frame]['col1'])
    ln2.set_ydata(dfs[frame]['col2'])
    ax.set_title('Frame ' + str(int(frame)))
    plt.draw()

#connect callback to slider 
sframe.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

This is what it looks like at the moment
[image]

I can't apply the same approach as for `plot()`, since the following produces an error message:

```
ln3,=ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==5,facecolor='r',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable
```

This is what it's meant to look like on each frame
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`fill_between` returns a `PolyCollection`, which expects a list (or several lists) of vertices upon creation. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to retrieve the vertices that where used to create the given `PolyCollection`, but in your case it is easy enough to create the `PolyCollection` directly (thereby avoiding the use of `fill_between`) and then update its vertices upon frame change.

Below a version of your code that does what you are after:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

#create dataframes
dfs={}
for x in range(100):
    col1=np.random.normal(10,0.5,30)
    col2=(np.repeat([5,8,7],np.round(np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1)*31)[0].tolist()))[:30]
    col3=np.random.randint(4,size=30)
    dfs[x]=pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1,'col2':col2,'col3':col3})

#create figure,axis,subplot
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1,hspace=0,wspace=0,left=0.1,bottom=0.1)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax.set_ylim([0,12])

#slider
frame=0
axframe = plt.axes([0.13, 0.02, 0.75, 0.03])
sframe = Slider(axframe, 'frame', 0, 99, valinit=0,valfmt='%d')

#plots
ln1,=ax.plot(dfs[0].index,dfs[0]['col1'])
ln2,=ax.plot(dfs[0].index,dfs[0]['col2'],c='black')

##additional code to update the PolyCollections
val_r = 5
val_b = 8
val_g = 7

def update_collection(collection, value, frame = 0):
    xs = np.array(dfs[frame].index)
    ys = np.array(dfs[frame]['col2'])

    ##we need to catch the case where no points with y == value exist:
    try:
        minx = np.min(xs[ys == value])
        maxx = np.max(xs[ys == value])
        miny = value-0.5
        maxy = value+0.5
        verts = np.array([[minx,miny],[maxx,miny],[maxx,maxy],[minx,maxy]])
    except ValueError:
        verts = np.zeros((0,2))
    finally:
        collection.set_verts([verts])

#artists

##ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==5,facecolor='r',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
reds = PolyCollection([],facecolors = ['r'], alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_collection(reds)
update_collection(reds,val_r)

##ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==8,facecolor='b',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
blues = PolyCollection([],facecolors = ['b'], alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_collection(blues)
update_collection(blues, val_b)

##ax.fill_between(dfs[0].index,y1=dfs[0]['col2']-0.5,y2=dfs[0]['col2']+0.5,where=dfs[0]['col2']==7,facecolor='g',edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5)
greens = PolyCollection([],facecolors = ['g'], alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_collection(greens)
update_collection(greens, val_g)

ax.vlines(x=dfs[0]['col3'].index,ymin=0,ymax=dfs[0]['col3'],color='black')

#update plots
def update(val):
    frame = np.floor(sframe.val)
    ln1.set_ydata(dfs[frame]['col1'])
    ln2.set_ydata(dfs[frame]['col2'])
    ax.set_title('Frame ' + str(int(frame)))

    ##updating the PolyCollections:
    update_collection(reds,val_r, frame)
    update_collection(blues,val_b, frame)
    update_collection(greens,val_g, frame)

    plt.draw()

#connect callback to slider 
sframe.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Each of the three `PolyCollections` (`reds`, `blues`, and `greens`) has only four vertices (the edges of the rectangles), which are determined based on the given data (which is done in `update_collections`). The result looks like this:

[image: example result of given code]

Tested in Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Your error

```
TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable
```

can be avoided by removing the comma after `l3`:

```
l3 = ax.fill_between(xx, y1, y2, **kwargs)
```

The return value is a PolyCollection, you need to update its vertices during the `update()` function. An alternative to the other answer posted here is to make `fill_between()` give you a new PolyCollection, and then get its vertices and use them to update those of `l3`:

```
def update(val):
    dummy_l3 = ax.fill_between(xx, y1, y2, **kwargs)
    verts = [ path._vertices for path in dummy_l3.get_paths() ]
    codes = [ path._codes for path in dummy_l3.get_paths() ]
    dummy_l3.remove()
    l3.set_verts_and_codes(verts, codes)
    plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not run for me; however, to refresh `fill_between` the following works for me

```py
    %matplotlib inline
    
    import numpy as np
    from IPython import display
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import time
    
    hdisplay   = display.display("", display_id=True)
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    ax.set_title("Test")
    ax.set_xlim()
    y = np.random.random(size=(100))
    dy = 0.1
    l = ax.plot(x,y,":",color="red")
    b = ax.fill_between( x, y-dy, y+dy, color="red", alpha=0.2 )
    hdisplay.update(fig)  
    
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        ax.set_title("Test %ld" % i)
        y = np.random.random(size=(100))
        l[0].set_ydata( y )
        b.remove()
        b = ax.fill_between( x, y-dy, y+dy, color="red", alpha=0.2 )
        plt.draw()
        hdisplay.update(fig)  
    
    plt.close(fig)
```