# Use both matplotlib inline and qt in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter (with IPython) to analyze research data, as well as export figures. I really like the notebook approach offered by Jupyter: when I revisit an experiment after a long time, I can easily see how the figures correspond to the data. This is of course using the inline backend.

However, when I want to explore new data, I prefer to use the QT backend. It is faster than the inline one, and allows to easily scale, zoom in and out, and nicely displays the X and Y coordinates in the bottom left corner. Moreover, I can use the QT backend to determine good x and y limits to use in the inline backend.

I have tried using the `%matplotlib notebook` magic, but it is simply too slow. For some experiments I am plotting ~500 spectra (each consists of ~1000 data points), which is already slow in the inline backend. Even with less data points, the notebook backend is just too slow to use.

Therefore, I would like to use both the QT backend, and the inline backend whenever I plot something. (So, whenever I execute a cell which plots data, it should both display the inline image, and pop up a QT backend window). This way, I still have a nice overview of plots in my notebook, while also allowing me to easily explore my data. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it is not possible to use more than one backend at once.
What I do is to switch backend and replot. I have done it with `matplotlib.use()` or `%matplotlib <backend>`, according to which version or environment I was working in.
I had the impression that this sometimes doesn't work or maybe it is not responsive, so I need to restart the environment. I imagine it is not easy to maintain it, so I am even surprised it works so smoothly almost always.

Available backends can be listed with:

```
matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk
matplotlib.rcsetup.non_interactive_bk
matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends
```

Hopefully here there are other useful info:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to run QtConsole, plotting with the plotSin function, both inline and through the QtConsole.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

..

```
def plotChirp(Type, Exp, Rand):

    # Orignal Chirp Funciton From:
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline
    x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, Rand)
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**int(Exp)))
    plt.title('A simple chirp ' + Type)
    plt.show()
```

..

```
plotChirp("A", 5, 200) # Plots inline if you choose
```

[image]

```
%connect_info # For your own connection
%qtconsole
```

QtConsole opens and now you can call your function to plot externally..

[image]

Using `%matplotlib qt` allows for printing in a loop, but unfortunately it seems to overlap the plots. Looking into subplots as a possible solution.

```
%matplotlib qt
for i in range(0,2):

    if i == 0:
        plotChirp("B",1, 400)
    else:
        plotChirp("c",6, 1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is not the QT GUI window I was looking for. I want the same window that pops up when one uses `%matplotlib qt`, *not* the QT-console (which does not have the nice scaling, zooming and axis property changing capabilities of the other window).

Comment: You may want to check out this post, as it allows for multiple plots to be scrolled through in QT Gui using a scroll though function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563295/visualization-of-3d-numpy-array-frame-by-frame/11563414#11563414

Comment: @tcpie i think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046299/pop-up-plots-using-python-jupyter-notebook it worked for me  `%matplotlib tk`