# pop-up plots using Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to have the plots created inside Jupyter Notebook using matplotlib to appear on a separate pop-up screen that would allow you to expand/shrink the image by hand? I've tried experimenting with (%matplotlib notebook) but that didn't really do the trick.

Just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use an interactive backend. This works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib tk
plt.plot([1, 2])
```

The notebook (nbagg) backend also allows for expand/shrink by hand. It has some rough edges though.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: :S only works if notebook is local (`TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0"`)

Comment: @ntg does it work if you connect via ssh -X you@some.server?

Comment: @Eric: It's been some time :S, normally `-X`, (also `-Y`) should have been tried, but not sure, it's definitely worth trying...

Comment: I tried it two times with my laptop ssh'ing into my desktop. Running matplotlib in ipython directly works nicely with -X, but the communication level needed for Jupyter Notebook seemed to be tough for ssh. There's a lot of latency.

Answer (score 2):

The tkinter backend is a bit buggy (windows 10, python 3).

I used `%matplotlib qt` for the matplotlib plot that we are all used to.